# (Robust) sigma estimate in statsmodels.api.RLM( )?

Tags: python, matlab, linear-regression, statsmodels

I'm am trying to port an algorithm from Matlab to Python. This algorithm uses the `stats.s` value from the `robustfit` function in Matlab, which I believe itself is based on (among others) the `stats.ols_s` value, described as "Sigma estimate (root mean squared error) from ordinary least squares" ([Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/robustfit.html)). I tried to implement the robust OLS algorithm in Python using `statsmodels.api.RLM` ([Statsmodel documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.robust.robust_linear_model.RLM.html#statsmodels.robust.robust_linear_model.RLM)), which seems to work, but I have no idea how to retrieve the value `stats.ols_s`: anobody who can help me?

MWE (Matlab):

```
a = reshape(magic(5), [25, 1]); 
b = reshape(magic(15), [25, 9]);

% Perform robustfit 
[coeffs, stats] = robustfit(b, a);

% Retrieve std 
std = stats.s; 
std_check = max(stats.robust_s, mean([stats.robust_s, stats.ols_s]));

% Discrepancy? 
rmse = sqrt(mean(stats.resid .^ 2));
```

MWE (Python):

```
# Import packages
import statsmodels.api as sm    # For performing robust linear regression
import numpy as np


def magic(n):
    n = int(n)
    if n < 3:
        raise ValueError("Size must be at least 3")
    if n % 2 == 1:
        p = np.arange(1, n+1)
        return n*np.mod(p[:, None] + p - (n+3)//2, n) + np.mod(p[:, None] + 2*p-2, n) + 1
    elif n % 4 == 0:
        J = np.mod(np.arange(1, n+1), 4) // 2
        K = J[:, None] == J
        M = np.arange(1, n*n+1, n)[:, None] + np.arange(n)
        M[K] = n*n + 1 - M[K]
    else:
        p = n//2
        M = magic(p)
        M = np.block(np.array([[M, M + 2 * p * p], [M + 3 * p * p, M + p * p]]))
        i = np.arange(p)
        k = (n-2)//4
        j = np.concatenate((np.arange(k), np.arange(n-k+1, n)))
        M[np.ix_(np.concatenate((i, i+p)), j)] = M[np.ix_(np.concatenate((i+p, i)), j)]
        M[np.ix_([k, k+p], [0, k])] = M[np.ix_([k+p, k], [0, k])]
    return M


a = magic(5).reshape((25, 1), order="F")
b = magic(15).reshape((25, 9), order="F")

rlm_results = sm.RLM(a, sm.add_constant(b), M=sm.robust.norms.TukeyBiweight()).fit()

# RMSE
print(np.sqrt(np.mean(rlm_results.resid ** 2)))
```

I tried calculating `stats.ols_s` myself using the RMSE, but there seems to be a discrepancy? I'm not an expert on linear regression so I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Josef's answer I now know that I need to look in the direction of the `scale` attribute: however, this parameter still seems to be slightly off (enough for me to degrade performance). I have tried using both `"mad"` and `sm.robust.scale.HuberScale()`, as well as turning both `update_scale` on/off in the `fit()` method, but the latter seemed to have virtually no effect.

I've written down my results below, my main question is whether this is due to numerical differences between MATLAB/Python, or whether some other quantity is being computed, and if so how to rectify this? Thanks!

```
# Coeffs:
MATLAB: [24.5477, -0.0098, 0.0136, -0.0471, 0.0032, -0.0217, 0.0032, -0.0471, 0.0136, -0.0098]
Python: [24.6229, -0.0096, 0.0136, -0.0470, 0.0029, -0.0225, 0.0029, -0.0470, 0.01357, -0.0096]

# Stats:
MATLAB: [ols_s: 7.7147, robust_s: 8.1826, mad_s: 15.1442]
Python: [mad: 6.7936, HuberScale: 7.8034]
```

Comment: The `scale` attribute is the robust estimator of the residual standard deviation. The method to compute `scale` can be either `'mad'` or `HuberScale`. I don't know what matlab uses.

Comment: Hi @Josef, thanks for the advice! I've edited my question as there still seems to be some discrepancy, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Cheers!

Comment: (based on a brief look at matlab docs) The only difference that I can see is that matlab divides the residuals by `sqrt(1–h)` and statsmodels does not. So matlab also adapts to `influential` observations. statmodels RLM does not take influence into account, it's a pure M-estimator as in original Huber model.

Comment: Also standard errors will differ. Statsmodels uses the original formulas from the Huber book.

Comment: Hi Josef, thanks for the insight! So, if I understand correctly, due to this difference `sqrt(1-h)` in the weighting function both the `coeffs` are slightly different, but more importantly, the robust estimator of the SD of the residuals is calculated differently. Thus, would a solution be implementing a custom weighting function in `statsmodel` (if at all possible) more akin to the one used in MATLAB? Sorry for the many questions, I'm just not very fimiliar with linear regression. Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: AFAIR, the standard errors should be about the same in large samples. However, statsmodels standard errors should have better small sample properties because it includes a correction term for it by Huber. (according to the theory, I never checked in examples)

Comment: RLM currently does not allow for prior weights (similar to WLS). Custom weight function (`Norm`) should work but it will be necessary to get the influence (diagonal of hatmatrix) `h` into the norm class and weights and other methods.